# Multivariate Calculus Vector Identity

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this identity which I am trying to show;

div($\textbf{u x v}$)= $\textbf{v} \cdot \text{curl}(\textbf{u}) - \textbf{u} \cdot \text{curl}(\textbf{v})$;

but have also come across,

$\textbf{a} \cdot (\textbf{b x c}) = \textbf{c} \cdot (\textbf{a x b})$;

and so using this identity why is it not true that,

div($\textbf{u x v}$)= $\textbf{v} \cdot ( \nabla \textbf{ x u})=\textbf{v} \cdot$ curl($\textbf{u})$?

My question is why doesn't the last identity I have written hold? I have been told it is something to do with the fact that $\nabla$ is an operator which means the vector triple product identity does not apply here.

Comment: The symbol $\times$ is written in MathJax as `\times`.

Comment: Choose an arbitrary coordinate system and note that $\nabla \cdot v = \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}$ and that ${\bf u} \times {\bf v} = \varepsilon_{ijk}u_jv_k$.

Comment: Do you mean $ \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i}$ ? Ie the same indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the derivative acts on both vector fields in $\operatorname{div}(u \times v)$. The other formulae would also hold if you let the derivative act both left and right, but it's a useful convention that derivatives act only on objects to their right.

Suppose, for instance, that $u$ was constant. Then $\operatorname{div}(u \times v)$ doesn't have to be zero (it should be easy enough to come up with a counterexample: $u=e_z$, $v=e_{\theta}$ in polar coordinates will probably do), but $v \cdot \operatorname{curl}(u)$ will certainly be zero.

You'll find you get two terms quite naturally when doing the calculation in index notation, one with a differentiated $u$, and one with a differentiated $v$, using the product rule.